# Is there a way to embed the Bing dictionary (not the bing translator) in my C# application?

Tags: c#-4.0, dictionary, bing

I want to get the data from the bing dictionary, not the translator, how can i do in my c# application?

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary you see in the Bing Translator UI is not available via the API.

Chris Wendt
Microsoft Translator

Answer (score -1):

[here's a c# implementation](http://dict4engkoo.codeplex.com/) ,also check out http://dict.bing.com.cn/io.aspx (bing dictionary protocol server).

Answer (score -1):

Actually you can directly parse the output from url http://www.microsofttranslator.com/dictionary.ashx?from=en&to=zh-CHS&text=sore

from = The original language
to = Translate to language you want
text = The word in the original language

> string source; //output from the url response
>   string translation = System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(source);

Language code see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh456380.aspx